# How do I split ammo?

Tags: apex-legends

How do I drop a specific amount of ammo in a stack?  Sometimes in a heated firefight teammates run out of ammo, but what really sucks is dropping your ammo and losing all of it, as opposed to splitting it so you and your teammates dont get screwed over.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can left click it, instead of right click, to drop one magazine. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/apexlegends/comments/ao4d4p/how_do_i_split_ammo/)

Answer (score 7):

On the X Box One, if you press start to open the inventory interface, and hover the ammo you have two options:

- A: drop 1 stack (generally 20 rounds)
- X: drop the entire amount in that slot (max 80 rounds)